# Data Modelling for TimeSeries data in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We are generating around 1GB of data every day which contains around 2Million docs. I want to store this data in elasticsearch. To store this, there are different approaches.

1. Create an index for every day (assume the index as test.22-02-2016) and store each day data in an index.
2. Create one index (named test) and create type under index for every date (as test/22-02-2016).

Please suggest me which one is good and why? Is there any other approach apart from this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO, creating separate index will be good choice

Comment: @PandiyanCool, is there any reason and why ?

Answer (score 4):

If you create a single index, you'll have to decide up-front how many primary shards you give it (you can't create new shards after an index has been created). Primary shards are one of the main components that will define the capacity of your index, since each shard is a Lucene index which consumes resources, and thus, have physical constraints due to the available RAM, harddisk, CPU, etc. So you may decide to plan enough capacity by creating (e.g.) 100 shards, but it's [not a good idea](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/kagillion-shards.html). Over-allocation is ok, but not too much.

Another thing to consider is that if you create several types within the same index they will need to satisfy a few constraints. Namely, if at some point you want to add a new field which conflicts with another field of the same type, you will not be able to do so, and the only solution will be to create a new index anyway.

For these two reasons mainly (and [a few others](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type)), you're better off creating a new index every day.

Comment: Did this help or do you still have questions/doubts?